# Error while feeding tf.Dataset to fit(): KeyError: 'embedding_input'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0

I'm using TensorFlow 2.0 Datasets to feed my model's fit function. Here is the code:

```
def build_model(self):
    self.g_Model = Sequential()
    self.g_Model.add(Embedding(self.g_Max_features, output_dim=256))
    self.g_Model.add(LSTM(128))
    self.g_Model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    self.g_Model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    self.g_Model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

def train_model(self, filenames):
    lstm_feature_description = {
        'X': tf.io.FixedLenFeature(CONFIG.g_keras_lstm_max_document_length, tf.float32),
        'y': tf.io.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64),
    }

    def _parse_lstm_function(example_proto):
        return tf.io.parse_single_example(serialized=example_proto, features=lstm_feature_description)

    self.build_model()

    # Start Preparing The Data
    raw_lstm_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(CONFIG.g_record_file_lstm)

    parsed_lstm_dataset = raw_lstm_dataset.map(_parse_lstm_function)
    parsed_lstm_dataset = parsed_lstm_dataset.shuffle(CONFIG.g_shuffle_s).batch(CONFIG.g_Batch_size)

    self.g_Model.fit(parsed_lstm_dataset, epochs=2)
```

But I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "keras_lstm_v2.py", line 79, in train_model
      1/Unknown - 0s 0s/step    self.g_Model.fit(parsed_lstm_dataset, epochs=2)
  File "venv_tf_new\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 728, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "venv_tf_new\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 324, in fit
    total_epochs=epochs)
  File "venv_tf_new\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 123, in run_one_epoch
    batch_outs = execution_function(iterator)
  File "venv_tf_new\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2_utils.py", line 86, in execution_function
    distributed_function(input_fn))
  File "venv_tf_new\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py", line 457, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "venv_tf_new\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py", line 503, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializer_map)
  File "venv_tf_new\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py", line 408, in _initialize
    *args, **kwds))
  File "venv_tf_new\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 1848, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "venv_tf_new\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 2150, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "venv_tf_new\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 2041, in _create_graph_function
    capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
  File "venv_tf_new\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 915, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "venv_tf_new\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py", line 358, in wrapped_fn
    return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "venv_tf_new\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2_utils.py", line 66, in distributed_function
    model, input_iterator, mode)
  File "venv_tf_new\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2_utils.py", line 118, in _prepare_feed_values
    inputs = [inputs[key] for key in model._feed_input_names]
  File "venv_tf_new\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2_utils.py", line 118, in <listcomp>
    inputs = [inputs[key] for key in model._feed_input_names]
KeyError: 'embedding_input'
```

I've seen this [thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19912), however it doesn't clarify things up for me. As far as I understood there is a problem with the loaded data, but according to documentation for Datasets it should work out of the box, so I couldn't figure out how to fix it.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your model's inputs somewhere, typically something like

```
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
```

Try taking out the last line in your model building function

```
self.g_Model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

and move it to your train function, once you have declared your model you can use the output of the model as your output layer and declare your input layer with something like

```
 input_size = CONFIG.g_keras_lstm_max_document_length
 input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(input_size)
 output_layer = self.build_model()
 model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer )

 model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy']) 
 model.fit( .... )
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself today. Actually, it was two errors in my code:

1. The *.fit()* function could not determine where inputs and labels are as noted by @NiallJG above. However, the solution provided didn't solve the problem, so I fixed it up in the following way:

   1.1 In my *build_model* function I've added "name" to Embedding layer:

   ```
   self.g_Model.add(Embedding(input_dim=self.g_Max_features, output_dim=256, name='X'))
   ```

   1.2 To match this name I've actually needed to change my *lstm_feature_description*, so it contains "_input" postfix:

   ```
   def train_model(self, filenames):
   lstm_feature_description = {
       'X_input': tf.io.FixedLenFeature(CONFIG.g_keras_lstm_max_document_length, tf.float32),
       'y': tf.io.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64),
   }
   ```
2. My *_parse_lstm_function* was returning data to the Dataset in the
   wrong manner, causing "*IndexError: list index out of range*" error. Here is how the modified function should look like:

   ```
   def _parse_lstm_function(example_proto):
       # Parse the input tf.Example proto using the dictionary above.
       parsed = tf.io.parse_single_example(serialized=example_proto, features=lstm_feature_description)
       return parsed["X_input"], parsed["y"]
   ```

This allowed the model to *.fit()* correctly, except now I've left with OOM error, but this will be covered in another question.